# How to fix pycharm Environment error while installing new packages

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, virtualenv, interpreter

I've set up a global interpreter (A new Project).
I'm trying to install new packages for this project so that I may use this project's interpreter for future projects.
while installing NumPy I got following error:

**Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '"C:'**

I ran Pycharm as *Administrator*.

I read a post and i suspect the problem might be due to spaces in pathname.
link-https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/11451

can anyone suggest how to fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. no (at least not automagically ... )
2. Install python ... install packages ... make venv's using `--include_site_packages` (pycharm makes this quite easy with their GUI create new venv thing)
3. I think you must have some globally installed python that you can create venvs from
4. pip is the python package manager, this is how you install python packages from the central repository (pypi)

the easiest way to install python is to type python in cmd.exe, this will take you to the windows store "install python" page, click the install button, when you are installing make sure you tell the installer to modify the PATH variable (its a checkbox that is at the end of the install prompts) ... then open a new cmd.exe and type `python` if a shell opens you are done ... if not you need to "Edit System Environmental variables", once you can type python and get into the python shell then try `python -m pip install numpy`